# How does one add perspective to a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a UIimageView and I need to give some perspective to the image. Maybe by modifying the vertex of the image...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UIImageView is just a kind of UIView, so you can use the answer given in [UIView perspective transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/uiview-perspective-transform).