# Change the z-order of subviews on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, exchange-server, subview, z-order

I'm developing a game. I'm using about 150 UIImageView to hold the graphics. I'm simulating a 3D enviroment, so i would like to change the z-order (how close is an object to the camera).

I know there exists :
[superWindow exchangeSubviewAtIndex:i withSubviewAtIndex:j];

But for some reason it's not working, some of the subviews disappear an re-appear.

Now I just remove all subviews and add it again in the correct z-order, this is ok with 50 subviews (on a 2G iphone) but with 120 it takes half a second so the gameplay sucks (I dont have and 3GS so i didn't try there).

I'm using so many subviews because each one is a square, then i colored it, resize it and move it somewhere in the screen. I'm holding the subviews under a NSMutableArray...

Answer (score 5):

The iPhone documentation often warns about multiple UIViews nested, as it has a large performance hit after a certain point. If you start getting into issues one option is to render your UIViews into an image and using that to lower the number of on-screen views, but if you're simulating 3D that probably isn't going to help much since your composite view would need re-rendering too often.

The iPhone has full support for OpenGL ES, which allows for a **real** 3D environment. Take a look at some of the samples and/or a good book on the topic and you'll find that it's much easier to simply use OpenGL.

Answer (score 4):

Z-order is an artifact of where your view appears in your superview's list of subviews.  The last subview added to the superview is "on top".

So, to move a view to the be "on top", you remove it from its superview, then re-add it -- making it the last one and, therefore, on top.

Here, a view moves himself to the top of the z-order.

```
// move to the to in the z-order
UIView* superview = [self superview];
[self retain];
[self removeFromSuperview];
[superview addSubview:self];
[self release];
```

Note the [self retain] to prevent your dealloc if your superview is the only reference to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to take the plunge to OpenGL ES, as Timothy suggests, you might want to look at replacing the UIViews with CALayers and placing them within a [CATransformLayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransformLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html).  CATransformLayer is new in iPhone OS 3.0, and it lets you do a true 3-D layout of the CALayers.  You can then set the [zPosition](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/zPosition) property on your CALayers to locate them in the Z plane of the CATransformLayer.  For more on 3-D layout of CALayers, I direct you to [this article](http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-3d-perspective/).

You can even add a nice perspective effect on the overall CATransformLayer by [setting the m34 element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/uiview-perspective-transform/353611#353611) in the CATransform3D applied to that layer.

Changing from UIViews to CALayers is pretty straightforward, because their structures have much in common.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a 2D game library like [Cocos2D](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/).  I'm pretty sure that supports Z-ordering, and the performance will be vastly better than using UIViews.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but you can change the z order with bringSubViewToFront.

See this answer: [How to set iPhone UI View z index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631878/how-to-set-iphone-ui-view-z-index)