# How to skew the image?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, gpuimage

[image]

When I press and drag the red rounded corners that corner only increased depending on the X, Y not for rest of the image. How to handle this problem. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: See the image. To drag the corners then increase the corner length. Are you clear?

Comment: NO, Suppose I tap on bottom right corner and drag little right. what must be the outcome? Do you want the image to be zoomed in/out or just move the blue bordered box?

Comment: I checked the out of boundary conditions, So thats not a problem. The corner rectangle are working fine. Only my problem is how to increase the skew for the 3D transformed image? Please give some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CATransform3D should help you solve this.
Maybe you can go through this [link](http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-3d-perspective/).
And Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353611/942966)

**EDIT**

Other related links:

1. [iPhone image stretching (skew)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351586/iphone-image-stretching-skew)
2. [How do I use CATransform3D on a UIView to add a specific type of perspective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275982/how-do-i-use-catransform3d-on-a-uiview-to-add-a-specific-type-of-perspective)

Comment: Thanks Roshit... I will check this link...