# UIImage perspective correction

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking for a way to apply a "perspective correction" to an image in an iPhone app.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/uiview-perspective-transform/353611#353611) explains how to apply a perspective distortion, what I want is exactly the inverse operation...

Any idea how to do this?

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was make use of an [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) port to the iPhone, that can be found [here](http://www.cloudgoessocial.net/2009/06/09/imagemagick-on-iphone-with-jpeg-png/).

Just in case someone else needs something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the transform has an inverse, if you have the original transform then you can use CATransform3DInvert().

If you have a quadrilateral (but not the transform) and want to map it to a square/rectangle, there's plenty of code out there — Googling [inverse perspective transform](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=inverse+perspective+transform) gives a few results. If you're working in homogeneous coordinates, then solve the matrix and invert it (or something).