# Spinning an image around like a coin

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation

I have one image. I want to **spin it like a coin** spin on surface. I tried rotation transform but it does not spin like that. How to achieve such an animation?

[image]

code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
lbl_facebook.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:12.0f];
txtPassword.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:15.0f];
txtUsername.font=[UIFont fontWithName:GZFont size:15.0f];

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.startProgress = 0;
transition.endProgress = 1.0;
transition.type = @"flip";
transition.subtype = @"fromRight";
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.repeatCount = 2;
[_Image.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];
}
```

nd:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

#import "RegistrationViewController.h"
#import "ForgetPasswordViewController.h"
#import "ForgetPasswordController.h"
#import "SearchServiceProviderViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531332/how-to-rotate-an-uiimageview-with-catransform3drotate-make-an-effect-like-door-o

Comment: Use `CATransform3DRotate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One good trick to spin like this is that take different images of coin with different  angle like spinning image. And then add all those images to array and start animation of images with that array..it will give you much better effect...Simple process like video framing.

Like:

```
NSArray *animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"images1.jpg"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"images5.jpg"],
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"index3.jpg"],
                          nil];
UIImageView *animationView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460)];
animationView.backgroundColor      = [UIColor purpleColor];
animationView.animationImages      = animationArray;
animationView.animationDuration    = 1.5;
animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animationView startAnimating];
```

Comment: @Elhoej Check my edited answer...and if it helps you upvote it :)

Comment: With this method, how do I set the animation to be spinning? Can you show me full code example? Sorry, can't get it to work :(

Comment: you need multiple images which simulate coin is spinning...and then you need to start animation by passing all those images sequence to imageview...@Elhoej

Answer (score 19):

This will make a nice, **coin-like** flip:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.startProgress = 0;
transition.endProgress = 1.0;
transition.type = @"flip";
transition.subtype = @"fromRight";
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.repeatCount = 2;
```

And add the transition animation to the layer of your view:

```
[_yourView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];
```

See it in action:

[image]

Comment: Why is it not working? Have you imported Quartzcore Framework?

Comment: Maybe post your code? Otherwise how can we help you? Help us help you.

Comment: @vivek, don't run the animation in `viewDidLoad`. It won't work, the view is not visible at that moment, frames are not set. To see it, run it at least in `viewDidAppear` method.