# How to rotate the UIView of greeting card

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, animation, catransform3d

I am making a greeting card app. To view the greeting card I have open the greeting card in which I have added different image view for different pages. It is a three page greeting card.
To open the greeting card i have used `CATransform3D`. But after opening greeting I'm not able to see the left side of the greeting card. I want the whole greeting card to shift so that I can see the first page when the user click on first page and vice versa.

I have added screen shot of greeting card. The left side is first page and right is second page.

[image: here is the screen shot after opening card]

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254552/opening-door-effect-using-core-animation

Comment: Have a look at this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587125/how-to-do-flipping-greeting-card-in-ios?rq=1

Comment: i checked the above link but in this we are closing the card i want the card to move so that one can view the first page and the second page should move upwards in order to view first page