# How do I add a map view to an OpenGL ES view?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I am making a 3-D iOS application using OpenGL ES.  I have created a square frame that gets rendered to my OpenGL ES context.

How do I add a map view to this square frame?  I'd like to be able to apply a 3-D effect to this map.

I tried adding the map as a subview of the OpenGL ES hosting view, but didn't see any 3-D effect applied to it.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be going about this the wrong way.  First, all OpenGL ES rendering is self-contained within your CAEAGLLayer, so you can't just add a subview and expect it to be part of your scene.  The OpenGL ES content will render within a flat layer, and anything added on top of it will just be stacked on that layer.

You could grab an image of the map view, convert that to a texture, and then upload that texture into your OpenGL scene, but that would probably have terrible performance and I don't think you'd be able to maintain user interaction with the map.

If you are just attempting to provide a perspective effect to your map, you could use a Core Animation CATransform3D to rotate the map view in 3-D and apply perspective to it.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/uiview-perspective-transform/353611#353611) for an example of how that could be achieved.  Using Core Animation for this would require far less code than OpenGL ES.