# Cocoa: is a "perspective transform" available?

Tags: ios, cocoa, macos, transform, perspective

is a "perspective transform" available in Cocoa (iOS, OS X) like that I see in Silverlight,JavaFX and so on? Other related thread was not enough clarifying to me so I created this one.
like this: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC270164.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView perspective transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/uiview-perspective-transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t set a perspective transform on a drawing context, but you can use a perspective transform to transform a Core Animation layer or layer-backed view. This is how Cover Flow is implemented, producing views similar to your example.

See [Animation Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/Animation_Overview/MacOSXAnimTech/MacOSXAnimTech.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004952-CH6-SW1) for a starting point.