# Tilt image with UIKit

Tags: iphone, uikit

I want to one board for dama game.. can we tilt the whole board and also show the checkers big to near and small to far.. Like see in attached image..

[image]

How to make like that .?

please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a perspective transform on the image or view. Here's a SO answer that might help you get started: [How do I apply a perspective transform to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/uiview-perspective-transform/353611#353611)