# MonoTouch: Transform image perspective

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, core-graphics, transform, perspective

I have this image...

[image]

I would like to transform it perspective like this via code...

[image]

Is that possible in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having tried it, but as Monotouch sits on top of its ObjectiveC counterpart and binds almost all its API, I would say yes and therefore you may want to refer to this question here on Stackoverflow

[Tilt image with UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105870/tilt-image-with-uikit)

and that one

[How do I apply a perspective transform to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview/353611#353611)

They deal with almost the same effect you want to achieve. You should be able to translate the code into Monotouch pretty easily.

Happy coding.