# UIView Animation Flip With Axis on at Top of View

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I have a `UIView` that I would like to animate a flip up. This isn't like `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop` because that places that axis in the middle of the view.  I would like to have the axis at the `top` of the view, so that it flips up similar to how a pad of paper flips from the `top axis` (NOT a page peel).

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.6
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTopAxis // <---- Wish there was an option like this                 
                animations:^{
                    // Exchange the views here


                } completion:NULL];
```

I am thinking it isn't possible to do this with the standard `UIView` animation options.  What is the alternative to this, where I can control the flip axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to enclose the view you want to flip in a taller, offset, transparent container view and then flip that container. In other words:

```
  |-----|
  |     |
  |  B  |
  |     |
0 |     |
  ||---||
  || A ||
  ||---||
  |-----|
```

A is the view you want to flip up; B is the container; 0 is the top of the screen. Apply your transition to B; by flipping B across its middle, you flip A along its top.

You could also do something more complicated and just implement the flip yourself using Core Animation, but this is a bit easier.

**Edited:**

If you want to take the Core Animation approach, basically what you need to do is apply a CATransform3D to the layer to rotate it around the horizontal axis, i.e. `theLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1, 0, 0)`. That’ll flip it across its middle, though, which is what you don’t want, so you also need to change the layer’s `anchorPoint` from its default value of `(0.5, 0.5)` to `(0.5, 0)` so that its “origin” is at the center of its top edge. You might also want to apply a perspective effect to the flip transformation using the CATransform3D’s `m34` member, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview).

Comment: I do like this idea, but I am wondering if Core Animation will give me a little more flexibility. My implementation is more advanced that what I described, and will use multiple flip views like this.  Would CA be faster?

Comment: Probably. Updated my answer to elaborate on that.

Comment: I had a chance to try this and am getting the following error: Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'CGAffineTransform' (aka 'struct CGAffineTransform') from incompatible type 'CATransform3D' (aka 'struct CATransform3D').  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you’re trying to apply the transform to a view instead of a layer. You need to do `theView.layer.transform = ...`, not just `theView.transform`—UIView does have a `transform` property, but it doesn’t do 3D, only affine transformations.