# iOS UIView Animation CATransform3DMakeRotation confusion

Tags: ios, uiview, 3d, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIView` that I am trying to animate flipping down, while having its axis at the bottom of the view. E.g.:

[image]

To do this, I am trying to use a UIView animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{

     // Flip Down
     top3.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
     top3.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1, 0, 0);

 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

     // Reset?
     //top3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);

 }];
```

Right now it isn't working how I want, it seems like the view is animating AWAY from the user rather then toward. It does't seem to give a 3D effect that makes it look closer to the user when rotating down, as shown in my image. I am positive that this is because of my lack of understanding how to use `CATransform3DMakeRotation`.

**Questions:**

- How can I make the view appear closer to the user as it drops? Such as skewing it as in my image example?
- When I set my `anchorPoint` it shifts my view down, how can I prevent this and still set my `anchorPoint`?
- <s>With `UIView` animation, can I use easing settings?</s> Used `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut` in options.
- Can I use gravity settings?

Comment: `M_PI / 2` is = to 90 degrees. Should answer your stopping half way through for a start

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that in my question and tested and it works. But I still have the remaining issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It’s not completely clear from your question, but it sounds like you’re not seeing a perspective distortion during the animation—the view’s staying rectangular as it rotates, right? For a CALayer to display with perspective, its `transform` needs to have the `m34` element set, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview).
- To compensate for the `anchorPoint` moving your view’s layer, you need to change the view’s original position.
- Yes. There are several animation options in addition to the one you’re using, and you can combine them like this (for example): `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`.
- Core Animation doesn’t really have any concept of physics. Depending on the effect you’re going for, you can achieve it by chaining multiple animations together with particular easing settings—for instance, a falling object that hits a solid surface would use an “ease in” animation on its way down, then an “ease out” if it then bounced back up.

Comment: Thanks, setting the m34 element worked and it looks much better. I also fixed my orig. position so that the anchor works. Looks like all my problems are solved.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, is there a way to know when I am halfway through the animation?  I want to change the UIView background color at the half-way point.

Comment: There isn’t—about all a UIView animation will inform you of is when it’s done—but you can accomplish the same effect by animating it in two phases, first running the 0°–90° part, then switching the background color, then running the 90°–180° part. If you use the right interpolations—an ease-in curve for the first half and an ease-out or linear curve for the second—then the effect should be seamless.

Comment: Noah - On the second animation block, how could I rotate my view 180 degrees, without using animation?  Basically, when it hits the second animation block, I need the view to be changed 180 degrees instantly, so the user never notices it. I tried adding some new transform options but it really makes things crazy.