# Safari 'Top Sites' style on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What would be the best way re-create the 'Top Sites' window in OS X Safari, in iOS? In other words, a curved wall of images.

http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/safari-4-focus-top-sites-browser-in-a-nutshell.ars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get something similar is to create a view for each “top site” tile, and set the transform on each view's layer to the appropriate rotation (around the Y axis) and perspective.  You can find more information here:

[How do I apply a perspective transform to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview)

This will not be exactly the same as Safari's Top Sites window, because Safari actually curves each tile.  There is no public API to make a view appear curved on iOS.