# How to reshape UIView like rhombus

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm trying to add a UIView to each side of a cube like the one in this pic:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Face_colored_cube.png

Since UIViews are rectangular shaped it's difficult to achieve what I'm trying. All I do by now is to rotate views but it isn't enough.

What's the correct way to achieve that? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a perspective view transformation.

[Have a look at this tutorial](http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-3d-perspective/)

[You can also look at this answer by Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353611/312312)