# CATransform3DMakeRotation animating trough zero (from -45 to +45 angle)?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm trying to do a simple horizontal flip animation with a bounce effect.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    front.layer.transform=CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), -1.0,0.0,0.0); // flip halfway
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) { // swap view
    front.alpha=0;
    back.alpha=1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ // flip remaining + bounce
        back.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45), 1.0,0.0,0.0); // final + 45 
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            back.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-22.5), 1.0,0.0,0.0); // bounce back
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.125 animations:^{
                back.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 1.0,0.0,0.0); // final
            }];
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Works well except for the 'bounce'. The -22.5 rotation transitions to 0 and than back to 22.5 instead of continuing to -22.5.

I've tried various values and also including an intermediate nested block that transitions the bounce to '0' before going to negative. Didn't help. The rotation always animates to a positive instead of a negative angle.

Just as a test, changing the 'final + 45' to a negative angle does however stop the animation at the desired angle. So the angles themselves are ok.

Problem seems to be doing a 'counter clockwise' rotation starting from zero or going trough zero. Values smaller than zero than always get converted to a positive angle.

Independent if the above is the right technique for implementing a bounce effect, how would a (nested) layer animation be constructed that rotates via CATransform3DMakeRotation from a positive (45) to a negative angle (-45)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rotating around the x-axis. Without a *perspective* on your transform, how would you see the difference between positive and negative angles? Without perspective, both positive and negative rotations look the same (the decrease the height). You can [apply perspective to your transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353611/608157) by changing the value in the third row and fourth column of your transform matrix by setting `.m34`. Search for "Core Animation perspective" and you will find a good explanation.

I ran your code above (on a simple view, filled with orange).
To more easily be able to see the rotation and the difference between positive and negative angles, I changed it so that it rotates around the z-axis.

These are four screenshots that I took during the animation. As you can see, the negative angle works, unless I misunderstood what you were trying to do.

[image: 0 degrees] 
[image: 45 degrees]
[image: -25 degrees]
[image: 0 degrees]

Comment: Thanks! When testing with the z access I could see that the rotations indeed worked fine. I will add perspective as you suggest to see if I'm just blinded by an optical illusion when 'bouncing' the view on the x axis. Looks however that way...