# Objective-c CATransform3DMakeRotation Clockwise/Counterclockwise

Tags: objective-c, uiview, rotation, catransform3d

I'm rotating an `UIView` along the **x axis** using  `CATransform3DMakeRotation` using the below code:

```
  float radians = DegreesToRadians(30);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 animations:^{  
        self.moveControlView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians,1,0,0);
    }];
```

The rotation is applied always in the same versus (**clockwise**). I want to rotate the `UIView` in the opposite versus.
In order to achieve my goal I've tried:

- Set a negative angle (-30)
- Set the angle to 330

But the versus of the orientation doesn't change.

I have also try to set `x = -1` leaving the angle positive.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You should apply a perspective to your transform, as it's explained [in the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10767019):

```
CATransform3D perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;

self.moveControlView.layer.transform = 
CATransform3DRotate(perspectiveTransform, radians, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);;
```