# Swift: Animate rotation of UILabel

Tags: swift, animation, rotation, jquery-animate, uilabel

```
let turnIndicator = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
turnIndicator.alpha = 1
turnIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
turnIndicator.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 31/255.0, green: 174/255.0, blue: 240/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
turnIndicator.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
turnIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 25
turnIndicator.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 31/255.0, green: 174/255.0, blue: 240/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
turnIndicator.layer.borderWidth = 1
turnIndicator.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
turnIndicator.text = "↓"
currentView.view.addSubview(turnIndicator)

let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
rotationAnimation.toValue = M_PI
rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0

turnIndicator.layer.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

I tried this code to rotate my UILabel, but it didn't work, i had another code to do the rotation animation, it rotated successfully but didn't animate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yu can use `UIView.animateWithDuration`, like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3) { () -> Void in
      self.turnIndicator.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI), 0, 0, 1);
}
```

`UIView.animateWithDuration` documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:)

`CATransform3DMakeRotation` documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CATransform3DMakeRotation)

Comment: it rotates it with no animation

Comment: Thats not possible, I am just running this code myself with rotation. Are you using Xcode 7.1? What target?

Comment: in the constructor of my class, my class inherits from NSObject

Comment: When is the class initialized? Anywhere in the viewDidLoad or else ?

Comment: in the ViewDidLoad of the view it appears in but not in the main viewcontroller, i just tried this code in my main viewcontroller and it worked, but here it doesn't, whats that all about?

Comment: Its because you are calling your animation in the viewDidLoad function, at this time, the view is not yes visible, so no animation can be seen. To see the animation, you have to put your animation code in the viewDidAppear.

Comment: another question, how do i choose the rotate direction? (clockwise or Counterclockwise)

Comment: I think this question will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330252/objective-c-catransform3dmakerotation-clockwise-counterclockwise

Comment: var perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
        perspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500
        perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(perspectiveTransform, CGFloat(M_PI), 0, 0, 1)
        
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
            self.turnIndicator.layer.transform = perspectiveTransform
            },
            completion: nil)

tried this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use `AnimateWithDuration` like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3/ 2, delay: 0, options: .Autoreverse, animations: {() -> Void in

var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)
    switchButton.transform = transform

}, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in

    var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    switchButton.transform = transform
})
```