# iOS equivalent of opencv's warpPerspective?

Tags: ios, opencv

Is there an iOS function that does the same thing as openCV's warpPerspective? If so, are the parameters the same?

Comment: If there are, they most probably won't be the same parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353611/1424355) has a good solution for perspective transform using the CATransform3D CoreAnimation transform.

As an alternative, if you don't mind converting your image data to OpenCV friendly format, you could just use OpenCV itself. It's a C++ library so it can link easily with an iOS project.

Here's an Xcode project with OpenCV already set up:
http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/