# How to change the perspective of the image view?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I apply a perspective transform to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview)

How to change the perspective, 3D Transform, skew ,distortion, rotation of the image view? Any sample projects for this.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question Im not getting you ...

Comment: can you please more briefly describe your problem

Comment: image processing like 3D transform, rotation, skew, and distortion. Any sample source code or any idea for this process

Comment: check out the openGL format for this or projects like FiltrrApp,NYXImagesKit etc..

Comment: I am using ordinary UIImage view not using OpenGL. Any idea change the perspective of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D transforms, rotations, skews, etc are usually done with `CATransform3D`.

As per the documentation ([Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html)):

> The CATransform3D data structure defines a homogenous
>   three-dimensional transform (a 4 by 4 matrix of CGFloat values) that
>   is used to rotate, scale, offset, skew, and apply perspective
>   transformations to a layer.

As an example, to do a 3D rotation towards the bottom right, you would do something like:

```
myImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, 1.75, 0.85, 0, 0);
```

and don't forget to

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

A fantastic sample project is Mark Pospesel's **Enter the Matrix**. [The code is on GitHub](https://github.com/mpospese/EnterTheMatrix), also check out the [explanatory slides](http://www.odysseyinc.com/downloads/EnterTheMatrix.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot. EnterTheMatrix is the great App. Once again thanks for your guide lines.