# Simple Core Animations 3D transform of UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I'm trying to make simple partly flip animation with CA, but I had a problems with perspective. I tried with:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.someView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    self.someView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI*0.6,1.0,0.0,0.0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // code to be executed when flip is completed
}];
```

**How to get this nice perspective?**

[image]

Comment: Duplicate question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -1000.0;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, M_PI * 0.6, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.someView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    self.someView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // code to be executed when flip is completed
}];
```

Comment: It's almost that, but needs to be outside, not inside. Gray line is fixed on image.

Comment: played a little bit with m34 property, (1.0/-1000) and now it looks nice :) thx

Answer (score 1):

[How do I apply a perspective transform to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview)

See answer in question.

Basically you modify m34 of the matrix which controls how much objects shrink into the background.

If you are more curious check out :
http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html