# Transform perspective in iOS(using matrix transform)

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, perspective

I'm trying to change image perspective on iOS, not by rotating them by x, y or z axis, but change vertices of whole image, using transformation matrix. I already did it, on Android platform. On Android I used from Matrix library method called setPolyToPoly http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html

My question is whether it is, something similar to this setPolyToPoly method from Android?

[image: This image i Have]

[image: This image effect i what to obtain]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374215/simple-core-animations-3d-transform-of-uiview

Comment: That question and answer to it don't solve my problem. I don't wanna change perspective by rotating them on x,z and y axis, like i wrote in my question. I need to use matrix transformation, because final image may not have regular shapes.