# Creating a non-rectangular uiview

Tags: ios, uiview

I need to create a uiview with non-rectangular shape.

[image: Trapezoid]

Using [Quartz 2d Paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html) is suggested in some post but i am clueless at this point and never worked with quartz 2d before.

Is there a any other ways to transform uiview's rectangular body into this one?

Thanks

Comment: Views are rectangular. That is not changeable. There are many ways to make them appear to be non-rectangular, however. It highly depends on what problems you're trying to solve. Do you require it to ignore touches outside this area? Do you require it to clip its content to this area, or are you just going to make sure you draw inside of it? Are there other views behind this view that you need to be able to see in the cut-out areas? Or do you just need to draw a trapezoid?

Comment: "Is there a any other ways to transform uiview's rectangular body into this one?" search for CALayer + transform + perspective

Comment: Only images will be placed into that non rectangular uiviews.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to dive into the CALayer transform.

Try this:
[How do I apply a perspective transform to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview/353611#353611)

Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html