# iOS 7 Safari tabs like view animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller, safari

I'm looking for ideas how to implement ViewController which will manage views same way as iOS 7 Safari is managing tabs.
I have to present multiple views in which are almost the size of full screen device. If anybody have other ideas I would appreciate that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/adow/WKPagesCollectionView) is the what you are looking for.

Good luck

Comment: very buggy and with comments in language I don't understand but gave me an idea how it should be done, thank you

Comment: @b3ginneriOS, I know its buggy. But its better than nothing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try using a UIScrollView to display your views. In order to create the 'perspective' look, you can apply a transformation for your views. For more information about this, you can check out this post [How do I apply a perspective transform to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview).