# image view with 3D rotation on Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, perspective, catransform3d

i'm newbie in programming (i'm a designer previously), and i want to create an iOS app.. basically, it just to create a perspective view of an image..

im trying to use `CIPerspectiveTransform` but it isn't what i looking for..

here is the code :

```
var ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
var beginImage = CIImage(image: imageView.image)
var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveTransform")

filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 200, y: 400), forKey: "inputTopLeft")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 300, y: 500), forKey: "inputTopRight")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 100, y: 100), forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 400, y: 200), forKey: "inputBottomRight")

filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
var filteredImageData = filter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as CIImage
var filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, fromRect: filteredImageData.extent())
var filteredImage = UIImage(CGImage: filteredImageRef)
self.imageView.image = filteredImage
```

want to try `CATransform3d` but don't know how to use it.. :)

anyone can help me?

thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview

Comment: http://milen.me/writings/core-animation-3d-model/

Comment: @rakeshbs : thank you for your previous answer. and now i have a new problem. i posted it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934454/catransform3dtranslate-issue-in-imageview) . do you know how to solve this?