# How to draw an Image in Perspective?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, core-animation

I found an app which has an arrow which is used as a compass. The arrow moves when I rotate my device. You can see it in the following screen shots:

[image]

[image]

You can see that the size of the arrow changes depending on its direction as well as the gray shadow behind the arrow.

**How can I create a 3D arrow with Swift or Objective-C? How can I make an image to appear 3D?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more like 2.5D, as it's sometimes called. It's a 2D image that's projected in 3D space. You can do that by applying a 3D transform to an image view's layer, and then modifying the m34 entry in the transform to a small negative value that gives the perspective. A value like -1/200 is a good starting point.

I suggest you look up CATransform3D perspective on Google. When I do that search the first link looks quite promising: 
[How do I apply a perspective transform to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview)

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted?

Comment: You're going to need to learn about 3D transformations to get the effect you are after. Explaining that is beyond the scope of a SO answer.

Comment: yes I did but I am a beginner and did not know where to start.

Comment: The code in the first answer in the link I posted is about as clear as it can be. If you can't make sense of it then you are in over your head.

Comment: Thanks for help I got it now. You helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: What about the shadow image. How do you make this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83813/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-sven-bauer).