# How do I animate a horizontal card pivoting (yaw) from its base to vertical?

Tags: ios, swift2, quartz-graphics

How do I programmatically via Quartz, animate a rectangle from lying face up (appear as line in 2D) to full height?

The following (pardon the crude drawing) is what I'm trying to get: a deck of cards (lines) with a card pivoting to full height.  I don't have any means of adjusting for *perspective*.

Possible modus operandi: 
 1) start off with a UIImageView having zero height. 
 2) Upper (xl,yl)(xr,yr) coordinates widening apart (adjusting perspective) as the height increases.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any reference, API suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply a perspective transform to a UIView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview)

Comment: You need to look into using Matrix Transformations, particularly the "m34" if you want to get a perspective change.

Answer (score 2):

This will be relatively close to your desired animation with examples for both UIView animations and CABasicAnimation.

To begin, let's set up the from/to 3D transformations:

```
let perspective: CGFloat = 1.0 / 1000.0

var fromTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI_2), 1, 0, 0)
fromTransform.m34 = perspective

var toTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 1, 0, 0)
toTransform.m34 = perspective
```

To animate with UIView animations:

```
view.layer.transform = fromTransform

UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
    view.layer.transform = toTransform
})
```

If you want to use CABasicAnimation:

```
let flipAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
flipAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: fromTransform)
flipAnimation.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: toTransform)
flipAnimation.duration = 1.0
flipAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
view.layer.addAnimation(flipAnimation, forKey: "flip")
```

**Edit:**

OP desires the anchor point of the animation to be bottom-center, this can be achieved by:

```
view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)
```

Comment: It's close to what I'm looking for.  The above code has the foci at the center of the view vs at the base.  But it gives me a start on what to study.  Thanks!

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee Updated to account for anchor point. I believe that is what you were asking for. Simply set the appropriate anchorPoint when setting up the view.

Comment: Yah... that's closer to what I'm looking for.  Shall study.  Thanks!

Comment: Great. Adjusting the perspective value will get closer to the effect you desire, I can't really know _exactly_ what that is though. If I can help more, let me know. Otherwise, please accept my answer :)